# Is it possible to create one NFT one at a time, instead of all at once?

Tags: cryptography, nft, cardano

Planning a project and just getting into development for cardano. I want users to receive a randomly generated NFT, but I don't want to limit the number of potential users.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah it's pretty simple. You just set the total supply to 1 and everytime you mint, you increase the total supply to 1 more. You'll have to modify your mint function accordinly to make it happen.